# In yaml file, variable's original value is getting loose while reusing the configuration

Tags: yaml, gramex

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
variables:
  my_pwd: 'Kt^$$&^dg#%o4Zwcat9knS)S#W'
  short_wait: 8

common_blocks:
  - &prod_my_pwd
    name: MY_password
    type xpath //*[@id="login-pwd"]: $my_pwd
    click: xpath //*[@id="login-sub"]
    wait: $short_wait

uitest:
 - *prod_my_pwd
```

This is my gramextest script, where In the Yaml file where I am Reusing Configuration

The variable '`my_pwd`' has **$** symbol in it and to handle valueerror in the case if **$** symbol available in the string I am adding **$$** instead of **$** (and the gramex -> config.py -> _substitute_variable() function handle this escaping of $ case value error)

but still in my script it failing and returning exception -> `ValueError: Use $$ instead of $ in Ve5$&^fh#%o4Znjtv9kmH)H#W`
So when I debug the gramex python function `_substitute_variable()` I got to know

1. This is working fine at first place when I am calling/using variable `$my_pwd`
2. But this is failing when I am Reusing the configuration which is - `*prod_my_pwd`

And the reason why its failing at 2nd place is -
at the first time execution of `$my_pwd` it replacing its original value and storing the returned val of `_substitute_variable()` and hence at the place of Reusing configuration its not getting the original value (with **$$**) of '`my_pwd`' and the function `_substitute_variable()` returning value error : `ValueError: Use $$ instead of $ in Ve5$&^fh#%o4Znjtv9kmH)H#W`

I am wondering how the `$my_pwd` loosing its original value and hence while Reusing configuration I am not getting original defined variable's value.

**Expected behavior:**
variable should not loose its original defined value while reusing unless and until its explicitly change/replace in script later

**Environment:**
Gramex version: oldest to 1.80.0

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample configuration that reproduces the issue:

```yaml
variables:
  my_pwd: '$$&'

url:
  a:
    pattern: /a
    handler: FunctionHandler
    kwargs: &alpha
      function: str
      args: $my_pwd
  b:
    pattern: /b
    handler: FunctionHandler
    kwargs: *alpha
```

With this configuration, Gramex fails to start. This is a bug.

The simplest workaround is to avoid `$` in the password [until the bug is fixed](https://github.com/gramener/gramex/issues/533).